# Weird corrupted string coming from strtok

Tags: c++, string

**UPDATE: Found some workaround. See below.**

I have written a C++ (nearly C except `new`'s) function in order to parse a string with a given delimiter character (in some way Cocoa's `NSString -componentsSeparatedByString` equivalent).

I was doing some assertions in order to test my code, I've used `strlen` for its first element.

Actually I'm using this function through an iteration. Not in the others, but in the first step of iteration I found out that string is `"A"`, however its length calculated by `strlen` is `4`.

So I went into debugger and printed out the values, the string was correct, however the values are characters like `'\xef'`, `'\xbb'`. It seems there is a memory corruption.

LLVM debugger also could not interpret stack variables correctly (I suppose), what does `0x0` mean? I know it is pointing to `0x0000000000000000`, but how did it come? It also couldn't tell the elements of the array.

```
#ifndef BUFSIZ
#define BUFSIZ 1024
#endif

char **componentsSeparatedByString(const char *string, const char *delimiter) {
    if (strcmp(string, "")) {
        char **components = new char*[BUFSIZ + 1]();

        //  Copying string because strtok is destructive
        char *input = new char[strlen(string) + 1]();
        strcpy(input, string);

        unsigned long count = 0;

        char *token = strtok(input, delimiter);
        while (token != NULL) {
            components[count] = new char[strlen(token) + 1]();
            strcpy(components[count++], token);

            token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        }

        //  Releasing that temporary string
        delete input;

        return components;
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Here are some results of debugger:

At first, `linesArray` is a `char ***`, which means array of array of strings. It contains strings parsed by this function through iteration. As this function returns an array of strings, `linesArray` holds all of these results.

The mentioned assertion was `strlen(linesArray[i][0]) == 1`. This assertion fails only in first step of iteration, where `i = 0`. There is nothing wrong after that, so I tried the second step of iteration first:

```
(lldb) po linesArray[1][0]
"P"

(lldb) po linesArray[1][0][0]
'P'

(lldb) po linesArray[1][0][0] == 'P'
true
```

Everything looks great. Let's do it for the first one:

```
(lldb) po linesArray[0][0]
"A"

(lldb) po linesArray[0][0][0]
'\xef'

(lldb) po linesArray[0][0][0] == '\xef'
false

(lldb) po linesArray[0][0][0] == 'A'
false
```

As you see `lldb` contradicts with itself. I couldn't find out why that happened. Is there a memory corruption?

Here is the code how I get the raw strings from file:

```
char ***linesArray = new char**[BUFSIZ + 1]();
char **lines = new char*[BUFSIZ + 1]();
lines[0] = new char[BUFSIZ + 1]();
unsigned long count = 0;
std::ifstream file("whoo.mmp");

while (file.getline(lines[count], BUFSIZ)) {
    lines[count][strlen(lines[count]) - 1] = '\0';
    lines[++count] = new char[BUFSIZ + 1]();
}

for (CFUInteger i = 0; lines[i]; ++i) {
    linesArray[i] = componentsSeparatedByString(lines[i], ";");

    for (CFUInteger b = 0; linesArray[i][b]; ++b) {
        std::cout << "line: " << i << ", command: " << b << " -> \"" << linesArray[i][b] << "\" : " << strlen(linesArray[i][b]) << '\n';
    }

    delete lines[i];
} 

delete[] lines;
```

Memory hex dump at that breakpoint, showing `0x100300340`, address pointed by `linesArray[0][0][0]`.

[image: Memory hex dump]

Any further information may be added upon request, thank you for your help.

## Update

Changed the line ending character from Unix to Windows, now everything works fine except last line. That may be also solved with another workaround.

Nevertheless I could not persuade myself to that solution, it's obfuscating. I'm using `libstdc++` (GNU C++ standard library) as standard library, `gnu++11` as C++ language dialect.

Comment: you show the debugging of a variable `linesArray` which does not appear anywhere in the code you show... so...

Comment: @bolov It contains the strings parsed by this function. Updating my question...

Comment: @Leviathlon now the post has become too big. Can you explain to me laconically in a comment what's wrong? For example, I will take your function, put it in a `main()` and then...?

Comment: at first glance `componentsSeparatedByString` looks ok. Your purpose with debugging now is to identify (or at least narrow it down enought) where and when the bug happens. You need to see if `componentsSeparatedByString` builds the tokens ok, next if `linesArray` gets constructed correct. Try it first with ASCII input then work your way up to Unicode.

Comment: '\xbb' is not Unicode.  It's the character with numeric value of bb in hex.

Comment: I don't see any way you signal how many tokens you have in `components`

Comment: Don't you need to use Unicode functions for this?

Comment: @gsamaras If I print a string came from strtok, it prints "A". However, when I look up its length via strlen, it says 4, means controversy.
I do NOT need Unicode handling. I just want to read a file and do some operations based on its content.

Comment: Also, Unicode is not an encoding, and there are several possible ways to write Unicode code points..  Are you using UTF-8?  UTF-16?  UTF-32? Something obsolete like UCS-2?

Comment: you have Undefined Behavior: it should be `delete[] input`. Compile with warning flags

Comment: @DavidThornley God. UTF-8.

Comment: @bolav, strtok() doesn't need to know how many tokens there are.  It finds token after token until it returns NULL.

Comment: @bolov No warning with `-Wall` at all.

Comment: @DavidThornley what I said has nothing to do with strtok. Let me ask you this: how does he know how many strings (tokens) are in the array returned by `componentsSeparatedByString`

Comment: @bolov If the element is `nullptr`, previous element was the last element of that array (during iteration over result).

Comment: @Leviathlon yeah, you default initialize the `input` array elements. Don't forget about the `delete[]` though

Comment: @Leviathlon (about warnings) yeah gcc doesn't give any, clang however: `warning: 'delete' applied to a pointer that was allocated with 'new[]'`

Comment: @bolov Completely true, I have to work with gcc however, so I didn't try that. Also I added the encapsulating function to the question.

Comment: @bolov:  Thanks.  Duh.  If Leviathlon knows there's enough tokens, that's good enough for debugging, but this needs either a way to pass back the number of tokens or at least initializing all elements of components to nullptr.

Comment: Ack. Please try to be as correct as possible in naming things. After all, your *compiler* does the same thing! "Unicode" is the *system* but unrelated to how the code points are stored. "Changed the line ending character from Unix to Windows" – no, line endings are not the issue here.

Comment: @Jongware Great to know that. Sorry for my illiteracy.

Comment: ☺ No harm done. The term you are looking for is "character encoding". "Windows" (whatever you editor means by that, as it's more of a category than an exact type) means all of your characters are remapped into `char` range, no more Unicode involved. And so it's way easier to deal with.

Comment: ... umm, I see you are updating your question as new insights arrive. While that is okay by me, try not to end up adding [`SOLVED!`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301) to its title ...

Comment: Why -1? Just tell me the reason and I will do what you want. Do you have an answer to question? If not why are you downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add better bounds checking for one thing.  I do not think that strcmp(string, "") will test for string being null, if thats what is intended.  It will only test for an empty string. Also, delimiter is used without being checked.

I also hope that you have code somewhere that is deleting all the code allocated with new in this function.  You need to worry about the string array as well as each element that is being created.

Otherwise I do not immediately see anything wrong here, though if you start working with triple pointers I'd question my design.  That being said you know what you are trying to do better than I, so I'll leave you to it.  Good luck.

Comment: borderline `not a question, but a comment`

Comment: @bolov, Do you mean not an answer, but a comment?  If so I agree with you.  I wasn't sure what the expected protocol was on Stack Overflow for stuff like this.

Comment: yeah, I meant answer.  It is more suited as a comment, as it does not answer the problem OP is facing. I haven't flagged it as such because it does provide some good points about the code and can be argued that it does have some value as an answer. It my opinion it falls right on the edge between answer and comment.

Comment: Fair enough.  I can move it if you feel it should be.  If not I'll just leave it here.

Comment: As it hasn't attracted negatives votes, it seems that the community doesn't feel it's a clear case of `not an answer`, so imo you can leave it.